# Аварийное завершение работы Eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ide, fedora

При работе в Eclipse(java версия) среда стала сама собой закрываться. Не надо выполнять какого-то конкретного действия, чтобы заставить его закрыться. Например, если нажать создать новый проект, то среда просто берет и закрывается и только, когда ее заново запустишь, тогда она позволит создать новый проект. И так ситуаций миллион. Если совершить любое действие отличное от написание кода, это может вызвать закрытие Eclipse.
ОС Fedora 24.

Результат работы в терминале:

```
[arsaran@andreyPC ~]$ eclipse CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode.forwardDeltaWith CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding.<init> CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates.instantiateTemplate CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage.addBinding CompilerOracle: exclude org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper.isValidSourceFile CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/tycho/core/osgitools/EquinoxResolver.newState
### Excluding compile: static org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataTreeNode::forwardDeltaWith
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb4c7b5cf31, pid=4432, tid=0x00007fb4ec2ae700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-3.so.0+0x46f31]  gdk_window_ensure_native+0x31
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/arsaran/hs_err_pid4432.log Compiled method (nm)  126182 10313     n 0       org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS::_gtk_im_context_reset (native)  total in heap  [0x00007fb4d6ee1f10,0x00007fb4d6ee2258] = 840  relocation     [0x00007fb4d6ee2038,0x00007fb4d6ee2080] = 72  main code      [0x00007fb4d6ee2080,0x00007fb4d6ee2250] = 464  oops        [0x00007fb4d6ee2250,0x00007fb4d6ee2258] = 8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Запустите из под консоли и покажите что пишет, ну и логи не помешали бы

Comment: "Довел" до состаяния, чтобы аварийное завершение произошло.
На сайте ограничение по символам в комментах, не знаю, как скинуть результат терминала.

Comment: Дополните вопрос

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: очень часто гуглится этот баг. gdk_window_ensure_native + eclipse и очень давно. или апгрейдитесь, или попробуйте вместо gnome  и gtk на какой-нибудь kde c qt перелезть

Comment: strangeqargo, серьезно?!! Это de виновата?! Ну, хорошо, спасибо. Если другого решения не найду, то на кеды перелезу.